# HTML img, alt="" isnt working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i got another question. Im using some icons on my website and in general most of the people who play this game know the icons but in terms they dont i thought, i could use the html alt="" thing to give them something like a tooltip.

I did set them up for the first row of small icons but i dont get anything on my mouse.

Is it possible to disable it somehow in .css? Im using a bought template so i dont really know what happaned here.

Website:  http://s526367159.online.de/reclaim/website/startseite/

Comment: title is what you want for tooltips, not alt.  Some browsers do (or did) process alt in tooltips but mostly alt is for if the image isn't available or doesn't load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`title` is what you want for tooltips, not `alt`. Some browsers do (or did) process `alt` in tooltips but mostly `alt` is for if the image isn't available or doesn't load.  Alt is a required attribute, so you still need to specify it.

```
<img src='megatron.jpg' alt='Picture of Calvin Johnson' title='Megatron aka Calvin Johnson' />
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `title` instead of `alt`

*edit* - you should still use alt - [see this article for more information](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/image-alt-text-vs-image-title-whats-the-difference/)

```
<img src="location" title="this is it">
```

Comment: Not instead of.  Alt is required for valid HTML.

Comment: @Devon - I understand the confusion - didn't mean to imply to not use alt, but for what he was trying to do - he should use title. I'll edit the response accordingly.